# Switch theme based images on scroll in React App with Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have a Next.js App with `styled components` that has a `day`/`night` mode (i.e. standard/dark mode) based on the time of day a user is visiting the site. So far, so good. On some pages, though I have a dark hero, so the navigation needs to be light no matter if the currently activated theme is `day` or `night`. Above that, the navigation is pretty complex and uses multiple nested elements, borders, and icons.

The way I am achieving this is having a state of `const [navBarStyle, setNavBarStyle] = useState('light')` that changes once a user reaches a certain scroll position.
Inside my styled-components, I am updating based on props and said state, e.g.

```
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: ${
  props => props.hasDedicatedHeroNavBar && props.currentNavBarStyle === 'light' ? ThemeSettings.colors.light
        : props.hasDedicatedHeroNavBar && props.currentNavBarStyle === 'default' ? ThemeSettings.mainColor
        : ThemeSettings.mainColor
      };
```

As you can see here now I had to divide the border properties into multiple lines as I can't pass theme settings inside template strings as it returns a function:
`background-image: url(function(props) { return getThemeValue(name,props,values); });` (copied from my browser dev panel).

It's easy to do that for settings I can split up (e.g. borders) but how can I do that for background-images, as the following does not work:

```
  background-image: ${
        props => props.hasDedicatedHeroNavBar && props.currentNavBarStyle === 'light' ? `url('/images/account-icon-light.svg')`
        : props.hasDedicatedHeroNavBar && props.currentNavBarStyle === 'default' ? `url(${ThemeSettings.accountIcon})`
        : `url(${ThemeSettings.accountIcon})`
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the abstraction up to component level where you can specify your styles per each icon or other component

```
const UniversalIconImg = (props) => {
  return props.hasDedicatedHeroNavBar && props.currentNavBarStyle === "light" ? (
    <IconLight {...props} />
  ) : props.hasDedicatedHeroNavBar && props.currentNavBarStyle === "default" ? (
    <IconDefault {...props} />
  ) : (
    <IconElse {...props} />
  );
};

const IconLight = styled.div`
  background-image: url("/images/account-icon-light.svg");
`;

const IconDefault = styled.div`
  background-image: url("${ThemeSettings.accountIcon}");
`;

...
```

Comment: Thank you, haven't though of the obvious!